# can't assign to operator python

Tags: python, algorithm

i have this code:

```
for k in range(0,player_competition[0]):
    max_player=player_name[i][k]
    score=0
    for m in range(0,player_competition[1]):
        if real_scores[m][0]=='?' or real_scores[m][1]=='?':
            prediction_real_difference.append(['?','?'])
        else:   
            prediction_real_difference.append( [abs(x-y) for (x,y) in zip(competition_prediction[k*player_competition[1]+m],real_scores[m])] )
        if prediction_real_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m][0]=='?' or prediction_real_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m][1]=='?':
            score+=0
        else:   
            if competition_prediction[k*player_competition[1]+m][0]>competition_prediction[k*player_competition[1]+m][1] and real_scores[m][0]>real_scores[m][1]:
                score+=10
            if competition_prediction[k*player_competition[1]+m][0]<competition_prediction[k*player_competition[1]+m][1] and real_scores[m][0]<real_scores[m][1]:
                score+=10
            if prediction_real_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m][0]<5:
                score+= (5-prediction_real_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m][0])
            if prediction_real_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m][1]<5:
                score+= (5-prediction_real_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m][1])            
            if score_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m]-real_score_difference[m] < 5 :
                score+= (5 - (score_difference[k*player_competition[1]+m]-real_score_difference[m]))
    final_scores[player_name[i][k]]=score
    if score > max_score:
        max_score=score and max_player=player_name[i][k]
    print(max_player)
```

now it's giving me the following error:

```
  File "prediction_game.py", line 58
    maxScore=score and  max_player=player_name[i][k]
               ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: Please intend your code

Comment: Why did you think that `and` was the correct thing to use there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `and` is your problem, that's not viable Python code.

```
In [1]: foo=42 and bar=42
  File "<ipython-input-1-98e4055570ec>", line 1
    foo=42 and bar=42
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

More specifically, you seem to be using `and` as a control flow operator -- that's a feature in Ruby (for instance) but not in Python.

Comment: Np. And by "thank you," I'm pretty sure you mean "I'll select your answer as the one that solved this ticket, since I appreciate the help of this wonderful community, and would like to participate gratefully"... right? :-) ;-)